# how to generatehash code of a string in c++ that will be limited range?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

I have on my configuration file 100 values. 
Each value is build of 2 char that can be like 90 or AA or 04 or TR or FE

I want to generate hash code of each value - and store them in array that contain 100 element - and each of the values from the configuration will be save in the hash code index in the array.

The question:

How to create hash code from 2 char that the hash code is limited between 0 to 99

Comment: `x % 100` wouldn't actually be *that* bad, but I suspect you want something better.

Comment: so let's say hash code for 11 is 88 is that you want?

Comment: no .. this can be value of AA and not just number .. also TR is valid

Comment: So they aren't hex characters, but what? Alphanumeric ones? Small/big letters? Special symbols?

Comment: no .. this can be anything with 2 char ... not hex ..

Comment: I don't understand the problem quite yet. Why do you need the hash codes... to store them in an array... sound bit like [XY-Problemo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Also, you have exactly 100 values, and you want to partition them exactly to 100 buckets? That's a case for [perfect hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function), and you need to know all 100 before constructing the hash function. If the key values can change, using a tree for such a small number of elements would probably work better. I agree that this is starting to sound like an X/Y problem. What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: the key value can't change. just need a way to map the hash from 2 char to int that will be from 0 to 99

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need in your specific case (mapping a fixed set of 2-byte sequences to consecutive numbers) is called [perfect hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function).

While you could implement it yourself, there's an open-source tool called [gperf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/) which can generate the code for you:

> There are options for generating C or C++ code, for emitting switch statements or nested ifs instead of a hash table, and for tuning the algorithm employed by gperf.